# Axios POST causes CORS error despite enabling CORS in Flask

Tags: python, typescript, flask, cors, vscode-restclient

I have spent many days on this problem and still couldn't figure out how to solve this. I'm having CORS issues and I've tried enabling CORS in Flask but it didn't work.

Backend code (hosted on port 5000):

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/process", methods=['POST'])
def process():
    print('process')
    # process here
    return jsonify({'response': 'OK'})
```

Frontend code (hosted on port 3001. I use react, only the function that sends the request shown here):

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';

const sendFile = (binary: ArrayBuffer) => {
    console.log('sending file');
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', new Blob([binary]), file.name);

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/process',
        // url: 'https://postman-echo.com/post',
        data: formData,
    };
    axios(options)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
};
```

Error as shown in Chrome console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/process' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and

> POST http://localhost:5000/process net::ERR_FAILED 403 (Forbidden)

---

I also tested with VSCode REST Client using this request:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/process
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=your-unique-boundary

--your-unique-boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="IMG_6651.PNG"
Content-Type: image/png

< /Users/johan/Downloads/IMG_6651.PNG
--your-unique-boundary--
```

It worked using the REST client so the backend is running properly. But I guess the REST client doesn't follow SOP. So I tried to see if it does return with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and it does:

```bash
% curl -I -X POST http://localhost:5000/process
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Werkzeug/2.2.2 Python/3.10.8
Date: Fri, 01 Dec 2023 09:37:22 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 23
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
```

---

Questions:

1. I thought I already allow CORS using flask_cors but it didn't work. How do I solve this?
2. Am I sending the same format of requests in my frontend and in VSCode REST client? If not, what's the equivalent frontend code of the request in REST client?
3. From the curl response, it seems `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is indeed included, then why do I still get CORS issues?
4. Is the 403 error a result of the CORS issue? Do I have two problems or one problem here?
5. I'm sending a simple request, which means there's no preflight request, correct?

Comment: Do you have any auth in your app? Try to issue OPTIONS request using curl and show what you get in response

Comment: Axios send a OPTIONS request first. Your app might be responding without the header after a OPTIONS request and maybe that's why it's failing.

Comment: I don't have auth. Sending OPTIONS request also returns the header:

% `curl -I -X OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/process`
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Werkzeug/2.2.2 Python/3.10.8
Date: Sat, 02 Dec 2023 09:01:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: OPTIONS, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close

Comment: @OlegWock It works fine on firefox but I get the same CORS error on chrome and safari. Any ideas?

Comment: @EduardoAguad does axios always send an options request first? I think I'm sending a simple request here. Any way to check if an options request is sent?

Comment: Does options request show up in chrome's network tab? I only see post request there. No options request.

Comment: It's not axios, it's browser who sends OPTIONS request. It's sent always, with exception of GET requests, you should be able to see it in network tab (but make sure to switch from 'Fetch/XHR' tab to 'All requests')

Comment: @thyu I believe that every XHR request does an OPTIONS first, specially GET. I suffered from this many times before. I suggest you to check if your app responds correctly an OPTIONS request with the proper headers. For example, Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Also, if you have nginx working as reverse proxy, you may configure it to respond to an OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasted so much time on this. I suspect it's some problem in `flask-cors`. As I just started, I decided to switch to FastAPI instead and it fixed the CORS issue immediately.

```py
app = FastAPI()
origins = [
    '*',
]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
)

@app.post("/process") 
async def process(image: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print('process') 
    # process here
    return JSONResponse({"response": "OK"})
```